# The printer edits are cut off at the top and bottom after upgrade cups to 2.2.6 with Postscript source

Tags: printing, cups, oracle-linux, ghostscript, erp

The background, we're upgrading a technical platform for our ERP that sends postscript editions in A4.

- Our old cups --> Redhat 6.1 / Cups 1.4.2 / Foomatic 4.0.4
- New platform --> OL 8.7 / Cups 2.2.6 / Foomatic 4.0.12

We use the same driver for all our printers, "Generic PCL 6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic".

We kept all the settings of the old cups (a few hundred printers configured).
On the new cups, the top and bottom of the page are cut off, about 1.3 cm (1/2 inch).

There are no specific settings on the lpoptions side.
The tests performed :

- old erp to new cups --> page cut.
- new erp to new cups --> page cut.
- old erp to old cups --> ok (obviously, this is our current production)
- new erp to old cups --> ok

I tried to put a lpoptions setting on a particular printer (e.g. `lpoptions -p printtest -o page-bottom=0 -o page-left=0 -o page-right=0 -o page-top=0`), no change.

I tried to take the ppd of the printer on the old cups (which is slightly different because foomatic has evolved a bit), no change.

If I take the ps file from the ERP, and send it to my printer:
`lpr -P printtest testfromnewcups.ps` --> cut file

If I take the PDF file that is generated in our erp and send it :
`lpr -P printtest testfromnewcups.pdf` --> uncut file ( ?! )
So for a PDF, the file doesn't pass the cups filters?

If I take the ps file out of the ERP, and send it to my printer in raw mode :
`lpr -P printtest -o raw testfromnewcups.ps` --> uncut

Anyway, I'm missing something but maybe someone can help me?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we've kept the old cups server for the time being

Answer (score 0):

Similar situation after migrating CUPS from 1.4.2 on OL 6.x to CUPS 2.2.6 on OL 8.x.
Our ERP submits print jobs to CUPS via a script that uses the following options

CUPS 1.4.2 had some sort of defect when using the option fit-to-page, so we removed that from our jobsub script.  Apparently we need to add that back with CUPS 2.2.6.

Comment: I think I've actually tested fit to page but unfortunately the printout doesn't have the same format at all, there are margins all around and the printout looks smaller.